connecting to snowflake from python using a key pair on snowflake.connector 3.0.3
I am trying to connect to snowflake from my python code, using snowflake.connector package.
unfortunately, due to legacy code I am constraing to use snowflake connector version 3.0.3 on python 3.7.3, and cannot upgrade
I did manage to connect from my own computer, using:
   con = snowflake.connector.connect(
       ...
       private_key_file = <path_to_private_key>
       ...
   )

so I know this works. however,  I use 3.8.1 version of the connector, and the private_key_file parameter was added later.
How do I connect using a key pair on older versions of snowflake python connector
